# How to execute manual offset acknowledge from spring ListenerContainerIdleEvent

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka listener that implements the acknowledgment message listener interface with the following properties:

1. ackMode - MANUAL_IMMEDIATE
2. idleEventInterval - 3 Min

While consuming message on the listener it decides if to ack the specific record via acknowledgment.acknowledge() and it works as expected.

In addition, I have a scenario to ack last offset number(keeping it in memory) after X Minutes(also if no messages arrived).
to overcome this requirement I decide to use ListenerContainerIdleEvent that fire each 3 min according to my configuration.

My Questions are:

1. is there any way to acknowledge Kafka offset as a trigger to an idle event? the idle event contains a reference to KafkaMessageListenerContainer but it encapsulates the ListenerConsumer that hold KafkaConsumer.
2. is the idle message event send sync(with the same thread of the KafkaListenerConsumer)? From the code, the default implementation is SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster that initialize without TaskExecutor so it invokes the listener on the same thread. can u approve it?

I am using spring-kafka 1.3.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, just keep a reference to the last `Acknowledgment` and call `acknowledge()` again.
2. Yes, the event is published on the consumer thread by default.

Even if the event is published on a different thread (executor in the multicaster) it should still work because, instead of committing directly, the commit will be queued and processed by the consumer when it wakes from the poll.

See the logic in `processAck()`.

In newer versions (starting with 2.0), the event has a reference to the consumer so you can interact with it directly (obtain the current position and commit it again), as long as the event is published on the consumer thread.